# how do you get a ui-slider to function in imacros extesnion for chrome?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, uislider, imacros, jquery-ui-slider

how do you get a ui-slider to function in imacros extesnion for chrome?

i am using imacros chrome extension 8.4.4. and chrome 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)

here is the code i was using in imacros (everything is working except it will not slide the ui-slider so i will only post from there down

```
TAG POS=2 TYPE=INPUT:BUTTON ATTR=*
TAG POS=2 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:X<SP>Enter<SP>the<SP>power<SP>0%
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:slider-vertical
TAG POS=2 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:X<SP>Enter<SP>the<SP>power<SP>50%
WAIT SECONDS=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:imacros-highlight-div
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:X
URL GOTO=en/logout
```

i know the CLICK command doesn't work with chrome, i probably have to drag the slider somehow but can not figure out the alternative to use with chrome, switching to firefox is not an option at the moment

edit:
i forgot to mention the function i am trying to activate

```
<span tabindex="0" class="ui-slider-handle ui-corner-all ui-state-default" style="bottom: 0%;"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can adjust the suggested below pseudo-URLs on your web site like it was done on 'jqueryui.com':

```
URL GOTO=http://jqueryui.com/slider/
SET S "window.frames[0].document.querySelector('#slider>span').style"
WAIT SECONDS=1.5
URL GOTO=javascript:{{S}}="left:<SP>50%";undefined;
WAIT SECONDS=1.5
URL GOTO=javascript:{{S}}="left:<SP>100%";undefined;
WAIT SECONDS=1.5
URL GOTO=javascript:{{S}}="left:<SP>33%";undefined;
```